# How to play decoded image frames (.ppm) in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, mpeg

I have decoded a stream using libmpeg2.After that i got lot of image frames in decoder buffer and I want to play it in Linux.How it can be done using C language.
Please help

Comment: The question does not clearly convey what you actually are trying to do. What have you done so far and what you actually need to do? Be more specific.

Comment: I am using a tuner which receives QAM64 signals.Using DVB API calls I performed Demuxing and then decoded the demux output using libmpeg2 video decoder (open source). After that I got image frames in a decoder buffer also I am able to save that image frames.

Next i want to take the content form decoder buffer output and give it to a video playing mechanism in Linux. How it can play ?